# python sqlalchemy как сделать бесконечную сессию / MySQL Connection not available

Tags: python

Я создаю подключение к базе:

engine = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}/{DB_NAME}", echo=False,  pool_recycle=1800, pool_pre_ping=True)

И далее постоянно работаю с переменной engine (24 на 7 в бесконечном цикле).

Проблема в том, что через какое-то время падает ошибка

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL Connection not available.
```

Как создать подключение, которое будет бесконечным ?

Comment: И зачем вам такая тормознутая программа? Может достаточно переодически открывать соединение для сохранения вашей переменной?

Comment: У меня 100 потоков и открывать соединение для каждого - лимит подключений, я не знаю как это лучше реализовать во много поточном режиме кроме как передавать переменную с подключением в каждый поток

Comment: Может поможет https://qna.habr.com/q/694547

Comment: у меня и так указан pool_recycle